# Modify existing class, deepcopy of mutable object gives same id

Tags: python, copy, deep-copy

I'm trying to modify an existing class.
The existing class should stay the same.

```
from functools import wraps
from copy import deepcopy


class OldClass(object):

    def method1(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Method1")


def wrap_cls():
    class_deepcopy = deepcopy(OldClass)
    orig_method = class_deepcopy.method1

    @wraps(orig_method)
    def new_method1(self, *args, **kwargs):
        orig_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        print('Method changed!')

    class_deepcopy.method1 = new_method1

    # OldClass is changed, as id(OldClass) == id(class_deepcopy)?
    print("id(old) == id(new): {}".format(
        id(OldClass) == id(class_deepcopy)
    ))

    return class_deepcopy


WrappedCls = wrap_cls()

a = OldClass()
a.method1()
```

Output is

```
id(old) == id(new): True
method1
Method changed!
```

`

This indicates that instead of `OldClass`, `WrappedCls` is used. This because `deepcopy(OldClass)` in the `wrap_cls()` method doesn't work:
It returns an object with same id as old class.

So I have to questions here:
Why does `deepcopy(OldClass)` return an object with same id as `OldClass`?
How can I modify classes at runtime?

Comment: I suspect that: ‘deepcopy(OldClass)’ doesn’t do what you think it does. You will be better off updating new instances of OldClass with new methods.

Comment: @quamrana Thank you for your fast comment. Yes indeed it doesn't do what i expected. Classes are mutable objects, so the id after deepcopy should be different, shouldn't it? Could provide a little example, where you "update new instances of OldClass with new methods"? I'm not sure what you mean.

Edit: i think i understand now. But i want to change class on runtime, to i.e. wrap methods. If i do this on instances this would have to be done every time i create an instance. In this example i could reuse WrappedCls as often as i want.

Comment: Couldn't you just _inherit_ from the old class and change what you need to in the new one?

Comment: @gimix You're right. Somehow i never thought about doing inheritance at runtime in a function. Maybe i overthought. I'll test it for my case.

Comment: (`class_deepcopy is OldClass` was more direct than comparing IDs.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Why…?`

> [This module does not copy types like module, method, …, array, or any similar types. It does “copy” functions and **classes** (shallow and deeply), **by returning the original object unchanged**; *this is compatible with the way these are treated by the pickle module*.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html?highlight=deepcopy#copy.deepcopy)

`How can I modify classes at runtime?`
(Just the way you started ("metaprogramming").)
To leave the pre-existing ("original") class unchanged:
a) [*Derive* a class from the pre-existing one](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance)
…
d) create a factory method and modify *instances*